# Parellel Uploading with AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, image-uploading, multipart

I want to bulk upload images parallel with Async task. Please suggest how can i use Multipart data to upload images like WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

For every file make new instance of AsyncTask and execute it.

Use this:

```
void startMyTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
else
    asyncTask.execute(params);
 }
```

Alternatively, you can use [this](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service) library for easy implementation.

Comment: Yes.. i have used this solution. For execute() code works good but for  asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);     gives iostream exception.

Comment: It is for Multipart/form data.

Comment: Yes, AsyncTask generates exception and for that you have to implement exception handling. You could use a try{} catch() block for  this.